# Generating or detecting a portable filename using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am looking for a way to use Qt to detect whether a file name is portable (between windows and linux), like boost::filesystem's [name_check](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/portability_guide.htm) functions can do. I don't want to use boost::filesystem if I don't have to, but I can't seem to find anything similar in Qt.

Comment: There is nothing I know of within Qt, but the page to which you link explains exactly what the boost methods do. I simple `QRegExp` might be sufficient.